# Extract a polygon shaped region pixels from an Image in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, computational-geometry

I have a float image stored in a float 2d array.

There is a GUI which displays the image (in grayscale). With the click of the mouse, I can accurately point to and show the original value of the pixel.

Now, given a list of Points on the image, a polygon (maybe a concave), I'd like to pick out the pixels inside of the polygon.

This is what I had in mind.

1. Create a polygon using modified Bresenham's line drawing algorithm. Mark and store the **edge** points for each scan line in a `HashMap<ScanPoint, List<EdgePoint>>` a.k.a HashMapList
2. Identify the points which are bent inside (where the internal angle is > 180 degrees). (To add them twice to the HashMapList so that they can be )
3. Use scan line polygon fill algorithm to pick out all the internal points.

Now, I have an issue with the 2nd point. I'm unable to differentiate between the below image 
[image: Polygon1]
where I'd have to add the "concave" point twice in the HashMapList to accomplish the task. Because it is creating two separate regions (one of which ends and other starts at the *same* point.)

and the below image
[image: Polygon2]
where I need not add it twice in the HashMapList, because, it is not creating separate regions.

How do I differentiate between these two pixels/Points?

---

Is there any library in Java which manipulates geometry on the images? JTS works on pure geometry and the Coordinate points are in float which is not very helpful.
The pixels in the image have integer coordinates.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote and close request?

Answer (score 1):

What you wanted to achieve is exactly Scan Line Polygon Fill (SLPF) algorithm. As you can see in these two images you posted, the only difference is the orientation of the shape w.r.t. screen space. But internal angle is an intrinsic feature of the shape, which is irrelevant to how the space is placed in the global coordinate.

If you can query the neighboring corner points from a given polygon corner point, check whether both neighbors are below, or above the current point, or check if both edges have the same max Y or min Y.